# How has angular documentation page opened their page as app

Tags: angular

Seen below on the angular docs page you can select to open their page as an applicaion. Does anyone now how this is done?

[image]

Comment: This is a PWA. [Here is the doc](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following my comment and because I have nothign else to do, let me be more precise.

This is a Progressive Web App (PWA) : this is a web application that has a manifest that all major OS can read (so not only Windows, but also Linux, iOS, and probably OSX, etc).

This allows you to see the web application in a webview, without the usual browser that goes along with it.

This has some limitation as well as some advantages, but I'll let you see [their documentation](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro) to know more.

be aware that you too have TWA (Trusted Web Apps) that you can even deploy on an app store ! [More information here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7JDFjeMvxos)

Comment: thanks for the information, Currently were trying to find a way around using internet explorer and this looked promising